# CAML Query get elements with most recent created date

Tags: caml-query, 2007

I'm trying to get the elements with the most new created date using CAML query in sharepoint 2007.

I can do it using:

```
"<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy><RowLimit>1</RowLimit>"
```

To get the most recent date and then use other CAML query to get the elements with that date.

But, theres no other way to do it in one consult?

Comment: What's your issue? You just add a ViewFields node to get the fields you want.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you're trying to do the SQL equivalent of a self join: Querying the maximum date in a subquery and joining back to the table on that date.

Unfortunately CAML doesn't allow you to do self joins; I'm afraid there is no way to do this in a single query.

Comment: Related - You can use SPList.LastModified to get the last time an item was created or modified - but no way to tell if this date was from a creation or update without further checking. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.lastitemmodifieddate.aspx